# Trying to make a script work to start en stop Shoutcast Dnas and Shoutcast Transcoder from php

Tags: php, jquery, linux, shell, plesk

I'm trying to build a php/jquery panel for starting and stopping shoutcast dnas and Shoutcast Transcoder.
So far as i'm now everything is working but i ran into a problem.
If i start the shoutcast dnas from php and i start after that the shoutcast transcoder then the dnas process quit.
In my php script i use shell_exec and i have made two different functions to call it.

```
}elseif($this->cfg->shellset == 'shellexec'){
    shell_exec($this->cfg->dir_to_cpanel . "files/linux/sc_trans daemon " . $this->cfg->dir_to_cpanel . $filename . " &> /dev/null &");
    $pid = shell_exec("ps -ef | awk '/[$radioport]_sc_trans.conf/{print $2}'");
}
```

This script is working but it seems that there is something that make it quit.
i run this on a hosting with plesk 12 panel without ssh access.

Does someone has the same problem or have a idea to fix this and let php run seperate processes in the background. I don't know of this problem is caused by plesk or something else but I can't find a solution for this problem have searched here on stackoverflow many times but no solution found.

I hope that someone can help me with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made changes to the script and rewrite some code and use ssh access.
I have used phpseclib for this.

the code is now

```
$pid = $ssh->exec($this->cfg->dir_to_cpanel.'files/linux/sc_trans daemon '.$filename.' </dev/null 2>/dev/null >/dev/null & echo $!');
```

this is working as a charm